# Silverstripe 3.3 - How can I save HTML formatted text into database from frontend form?

Tags: php, html, textarea, silverstripe, formatted-text

I'd like to allow users on my site to submit plain text comments. When I present these comments on my site, I'd like them to be shown as HTML (ie: in a `<p>` tag and new lines as `<br>`).

How can I present the plain text as HTML in Silverstripe 3.3?

I have a Dataobject with

```
private static $db = array (
        'MyText' => 'HTMLText',
);
```

and a form:

```
public function MyForm() {
      $myForm = Form::create(
          $this,
          __FUNCTION__,
          FieldList::create(
              HtmlEditorField::create('MyText')
          ),
          FieldList::create(
              FormAction::create('submit','Submit')
          )
      );
      return $myForm;
}
```

When my submit function is like this

```
public function submit($data, $form) {
      $myDataobject = new MyDataobject();
      $form->saveInto($myDataobject);
      $myDataobject->write();

      $form->sessionMessage('Message saved.','good');
      return $this->redirectBack();
}
```

Currently it saves the text as a plain text string without any HTML.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this. What do you mean by "simple string"? What HTML are you adding that's getting stripped?

Comment: What I mean is, when a user write some text in the textarea field and there are some breaks/paragraphs in the text I want so save the text with html tags in my database like: "<p>Hi,<br>I have a question... (...)</p>"

Comment: Ah, a textarrafield is quite different to an HtmlEditorField as shown in your example code.

Comment: ok, I found a solution. I just have to save the content with the php function nl2br: nl2br($data['MyText']).

Comment: You might self-answer your question then. Though it might be a security issue to allow every user html saved to db... Be sure, user input sanitised (and e.g. javascript is stripped out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - from your comment it appears your example code isn't what you're actually doing and you're using a `TextareaField` instead of an `HTMLEditorField`.

This is fine, so you have a couple of choices:

1. Add the HTML before writing the form submission:

   public function submit($data, $form) {
         $myDataobject = new MyDataobject();
         $form->saveInto($myDataobject);
         $myDataobject->MyText = sprintf('

   %s

   ', nl2br(Convert::raw2xml($data['MyText'])));
         $myDataobject->write();

   ```
     $form->sessionMessage('Message saved.','good');
     return $this->redirectBack();
   ```

   }

Please note the use of `Convert::raw2html` - without this, you'll likely be vulnerable to a malicious user who submits HTML to perform an HTML injection attack.

2. Add a setter on the Model:

   class MyDataobject extends DataObject {

   ...

   ```
   public function setMyText($value) {
       return $this->setField('MyText', sprintf('<p>%s</p>', nl2br(Convert::raw2xml($value)));
   }
   ```

   }

This approach will likely be quite fragile as any time the value is set, it'll be encoded which could be when you're deliberately setting HTML.

Recommended solution: #1

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution #1 works, but I had to use raw2htmlatt instead of raw2html because raw2html doesn't exist in SS 3.3. And: I am not using a TextareaField, I am using a HTMLEditorField, but using it in a frontend form shows me a simple textarea field with the attribute tinymce="true". Anyway it saved the text without breaks. With your solution it works now.

Comment: Ah, sorry - it's `Convert::raw2xml`